# How to get the user's score from leaderboard? - Swift

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit

I'm working on a game that messes with the leaderboard and the best player score. I would like that when he enters the app it synchronizes with his score saved in the leaderboard, but I didn't find ANYTHING that simply returns the value to me.

I know how to define:

```swift
public func setHighScore(score:Int) ->Void {
    if (self.localUser.isAuthenticated) {
        GKLeaderboard.submitScore(score, context: 0, player: self.localUser, leaderboardIDs: ["lbHighScore"], completionHandler: {error in} )
    }
}
```

What i want is something like this:

```swift
public func getHighScore() ->Int{
    if (self.localUser.isAuthenticated) {
        return GKLeaderboardScore      // <- this is the score svaed on leaderboard as integer
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: how about this method 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkleaderboard/3577540-loadentries

Comment: Okay, but how do I use it? How would an implementation of this that would bring me the entire saved on the leaderboard would be? @Kawa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of work I managed to find!1

Let's start:

The way it works when accessing the game center is asynchronous, that is, in parallel. To avoid errors and "delays" when receiving and saving information, I recommend saving in `UserDefault`.
So when you get the data it will be saved in a global variable. You can't just return the value once you get it because it's inside a `completionHandler`, where the return is `Void`.

To access the user information you need to access the [`GKLeaderboard.Entry`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkleaderboard/entry) class where it has the `.score` method that saves the score that shows on leaderboard. But the only way to access this method is with the standard functions that will return this information when the user is passed by parameter.

.

**First step:** access the leaderboard with the [`GKLeaderboard.loadLeaderboards`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkleaderboard/3577542-loadleaderboards) function. In this function, as a parameter:

- List with the id of the leaderboards that will be accessed

In addition to the `completionHandler` which will return two instances:

- A list of leaderboards
- Variable for error handling (`Error`)

```swift
class func loadLeaderboards(
    IDs leaderboardIDs: [String]?, 
    completionHandler: @escaping ([GKLeaderboard]?, Error?) -> Void
)
```

.

**Second step:** access leaderboard data. For this we will use the [`GKLeaderboard.loadEntries`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkleaderboard/3577541-loadentries) method. In it we will pass as a parameter:

- A list of users we will access
- In which period of the leaderboard it will be accessed

In addition to the `completionHandler` which will return two instances:

- The `.Entry` class of the local user **(is exactly what i want)**
- A list with the `.Entry` class in case of more than one user
- Variable for error handling (`Error`)

```swift
func loadEntries(
    for players: [GKPlayer], 
    timeScope: GKLeaderboard.TimeScope, 
    completionHandler: @escaping (GKLeaderboard.Entry?,[GKLeaderboard.Entry]?, Error?) -> Void
)
```

.

So, mixing the two classes, the function to get the user's score in a given leaderboard is:

```swift
// Function that takes information and saves it to UserDefault
func getHighScoreFromLeadboard() ->Void {
    // Check if the user is authenticated
    if (GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated) {
        // Load the leaderboards that will be accessed
        GKLeaderboard.loadLeaderboards(
                        IDs: ["idLeaderboard"]          // Leaderboards'id  that will be accessed
                        ) { leaderboards, _ in          // completionHandler 01: .loadLeaderboards 
                        
            // Access the first leaderboard
            leaderboards?[0].loadEntries(
                                for: [GKLocalPlayer.local], // User who will be accessed within the leaderboard, in this case the local user
                                timeScope: .allTime)        // Choose which period of the leaderboard you will access (all time, weekly, daily...)
                                { player, _, _ in           // completionHandler 02: .loadEntries
                                
                // Save on UserDefault
                UserDefaults.standard.set(player?.score, forKey: "score")
            }
        }
    }
}
```